# Convert JSON array to object or access certain nodes on JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I am using jQuery to make an ajax request to an MVC controller which then submits an object, and returns back a JSON representation of the object which gets returned back to ajax request.  The JSON that is being returned looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Account_LocationDevices": [],
    "Account_ChannelTransactions": [],
    "Account_Location_PaymentTypes": [],
    "ID": 56,
    "AccountID": 1,
    "Name": "b",
    "Address1": "",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "",
    "ZipCode": "",
    "Country": "",
  }
]
```

I then need to be able to access certain 'nodes' of this JSON array, or convert this back into an object and access it via the object. Anyone have any suggestions on how to take this JSON result and transform it back into an object or access certain parts of the array, without using index numbers in case a schema were changed?

Here is the jQuery doing the work

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "../Company/MicrosoftRMSStoreOperations",
                            data: { locationName: inputValue },
                            datatype: "json",
                            beforeSend: function () {

                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("Location successfully added!");
                                $('#locationDropDown').append(
                                    $('<option></option>').val().html()
                                );
                                $('#inputAddLocation').val("");
                                $('#AddLocation').animate({
                                width: 'toggle',
                                }, 100, function() {
                                //after animation
                                });
                               // window.location.href = window.location.href;
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Appears the database Gods did not agree");
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line on success:

```
 var json = $.parseJSON(data);
```

I could then access the array like this 'json[0].ID' or 'json[0].Name'

Final look at the code implemented...

```
 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "../Company/MicrosoftRMSStoreOperations",
                            data: { locationName: inputValue },
                            datatype: "json",
                            beforeSend: function () {

                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                                alert("Location successfully added!");
                                $('#locationDropDown').append(
                                    $('<option></option>').val(json[0].ID.toString()).html(json[0].Name)
                                );
                                $('#inputAddLocation').val("");
                                $('#AddLocation').animate({
                                width: 'toggle',
                                }, 100, function() {
                                //after animation
                                });
                               // window.location.href = window.location.href;
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Appears the database Gods did not agree");
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all that is not json response, this is an example :

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://json.org/example.html

if you use the $.post method of Jquery, you can specify the last parameter as 'json' and then you can get the elements like : (i am assuming you provide the json structure in your controller code)

```
var loc = data.Account_LocationDevices;
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I have tried that but it returns as 'undefined' ... and the controller is what puts the object into the JSON array and then just returns the array.

Comment: I believe what is being returned back is an array, I would then like to be able to turn that array into an object

Comment: Unfortunately it did not, but I did find how to access it properly and am posting the answer...I appreciate the help @LostMohican

Comment: Have to wait 7 hours to post the answer...#lame